# How do I determine and install the most up-to-date Intel graphics driver on Mint?

Tags: linux-mint, drivers, intel-graphics

I installed Mint on a Dell Xps 13 and have had CPU/graphics issues, specifically, strong coil whine and infrequent screen flashes. On Windows on the same machine it mostly cleared up with a graphics update so I'm hoping for similar luck on Mint.

System info:

```
Linux Mint 18.3 Cinnamon 64-bit
Cinnamon Version 3.6.7
Linux Kernel 4.13.0-32-generic
Processor Intel(c) Core(TM) i7-7560U CPU @ 2.40GHz x 2
Memory 15.6 GiB
Hard Drives 14.2 GiB
Graphics Card Intel Corporation Device 5926
```

Graphic card info (I think):

```
$ grep 'Setting driver:' /var/log/Xorg.0.log
[     6.209] (II) intel(0): Using Kernel Mode Setting driver: i915, version 1.6.0 20170619
```

Driver manager says "No proprietary drivers are in use."

I found https://01.org/linuxgraphics/ but this site is not very explanatory. I don't really know what a graphics stack is, and presumably I only need one layer, and I don't know which.

I did attempt to install their installer which gave me `libpackageglib2-18(>=0.9.4)` not available. I could chase that down if I knew I was on the right track.

To know whether I'm on the right driver, it would be good if I can learn

1. From my system, what driver am I using?
2. From information on the Internet, what driver is current for my system?

And of course I would like to install that driver.

Comment: Intel graphics drivers are included with the kernel on linux. To upgrade them, upgrade the kernel.

Answer (score 1):

To check which video drivers are installed in the operating system

https://askubuntu.com/questions/893737/ubuntu-16-10-on-dell-xps-13-9360-how-do-i-use-intel-graphics-drivers

correctly said @cas that the video driver Intel is included in the Linux kernel. To update the video driver, you need to update the kernel. To update the video driver from the  https://01.org/ site, simply connect the repository `01.org` (only consider this https://01.org/linuxgraphics/forum/graphics-installer-discussions/new-ubuntu-16.04-packages-use-unknown-key-again) and `apt update`or download and run https://01.org/linuxgraphics/downloads/intel-graphics-update-tool-linux-os-v2.0.6

although your problem may not be this. Decision:

https://www.dell.com/community/General/XPS-13-9360-QHD-random-screen-flicker-flash/m-p/5144342

Answer (score -1):

Open this link https://pkgs.org/download/libpackagekit-glib2-18 and download the libpackageglib2-18 for Ubuntu 17.10. install it and do the Intel's installation process again. Good luck.!